# Can't override android colors

Tags: android, color-scheme, overriding

I am using library for date and time pikers(https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).

And there is a saying:

"Alternatively, you can theme the pickers by overwriting the color resources mdtp_accent_color and mdtp_accent_color_dark in your project."

So I override this two colors with my own, but when I run app it still the libraries colors, but not mine.

Maybe some one have the same problem or maybe you have some idea why it happens?

**EDIT:**
Here is how I override colors:

```
<color name="mdtp_accent_color">#08395b</color>
<color name="mdtp_accent_color_dark">#062d48</color>
```

Comment: How are you "overriding" the library's colors?

Comment: please take a look, i update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the order in which the library looks for colors:

1. Color set in java
2. If on 5.0+: color set in `android.R.attr.colorAccent`
3. Color set in `R.attr.colorAccent`
4. Color set in `R.color.mdtp_accent_color`

If `R.attr.colorAccent` is defined in your application (for example because you are using a recent version of the AppCompat support library), you cannot use `R.color.mdtp_accent_color` to overwrite it.
If you want to use a different color, I recommend you to set in your java code when instantiating the dialog:

```
tpd.setAccentColor(myColor);
```

Comment: hm, I am using 4.0 v, and hevan't set R.color.colorAccent in my color...
tpd.setAccentColor(myColor); works fine, but auto-defined dark color sometimes looks ugly :)
If you would add tpd.setAccentColorDark(myColor); - I think it would be perfect!

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect that it is looking at theme attributes, rather than color names.